# Connection error even after calling sql.close()

Tags: node.js

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server node. If that fails, I want to try to connect to another node.

```
       sql.connect(config, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            sql.close();

            //Setting the server to the secondary node's IP
            config.server = secret.secondary
            sql.connect(config, (err) => { 
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                }
            })       
        } else {
      }
```

But when I try to run this, I get the following error -

`Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment on your question instead of writing an answer but I couldn't because I don't have enough reputation. Try using `ConnectionPool` as in the following example.

```
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);

pool.connect(err => {
    if(err) {
        config.server = secret.secondary;
        pool.connect(err => {
            if(err) callback(err);
        });
    }
});
```